# Define multiple specific dates efficiently

Tags: r, date

I try to optimize my code. How can I define specific dates more efficiently to use them later on? For example:

```
Monday <- as.Date("23.01.2021", "%d.%m.%Y")
Tuesday <- as.Date("04.04.2020", "%d.%m.%Y")
Wednesday <- as.Date("15.09.2021", "%d.%m.%Y")
Thursday <- as.Date("30.03.2021", "%d.%m.%Y")
Friday <- as.Date("08.08.2019", "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Very much depends on how you want to use it.

One way could be to create a named vector.

Maybe 5 days from a specified date

```
dateV <- as.Date("2021-08-23") + 1:5
```

Or dates in between a range

```
dateV <-seq(as.Date("2021-08-23"), as.Date("2021-08-27"), by="days")
```

Then add the names of the weekdays.

```
names(dateV) <- weekdays(dateV)
```

From there you can get the required DoW like so

```
dateV['Wednesday']
```

Also if you're working with dates I'd familiarise yourself with the `lubridate` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What would be an easy option to specify the dates within a list?